SARSA Implementation - how to arrive at a convergence constraint, if the optimal value function is not known?
I have an Inverted pendulum domain, where I need to discretize state space (defined by 2 state variables - angle and angular velocity with given ranges) and action space (torque values with given bounds) and implement a SARSA algorithm, to arrive at optimal q-value and optimal policy. Each episode terminates after a fixed no. of time steps say T (and is not defined by any specific terminal state).
I'm confused on how to decide when the algorithm has converged?
Let's say I use a epsilon greedy action, with some epsilon say 0.1, and learning rate say 0.05 to do the TD update in each iteration, and say a discount factor of 1. Now of course I have to tweak these hyperparameters (epsilon, alpha (learning rate), q-value initialization (random/zero/optimistic, etc) to figure out the best performing values.  There is an equation defined to compute reward - as a function of angle, angular velocity in each time step (which I believe can be abstracted to answer this question). First, I start by discretizing the states and actions to random no. of bin, say 1 bin, for each unit difference. (for eg. torque --> -2->(-1),(-1)->0, 0->1, 1->2, etc)
I don't know what the optimal value function is, however, I know for the policy to be considered good, the expected reward -200 or better. How to use this to arrive at a convergence constraint for my SARSA implementation.
